# Execute a method when DOM finishes rendering the elements

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

On my app the HomePage has a component that receives an "options object" from the sidemenu(another component).

The menu has an "Publish" button and when I pressed it. It notifies my home *`observable`* to update the component.

Which notifies back another *`observable`*(home) that It received an updated the model.

The component then (through a `*ngIf*`) show/hide some DOM elements accordingly.

**The problem is:**
When a get the "back notification" I run a JavaScript function on the rendered elements. But I doesn't work simply because it performs first than DOM rendering.

So you guys know any approach to listener DOM? So when it finish the render I can call the function?

If it was a ngFor I could make it work using directives on (last) variable. But its not the case...

Comment: use `setTimeout` or bind to the last lifecycle hooks, `ngAfterViewChecked` or `ngAfterContentChecked`. Consider also providing a [mcve].

Comment: Can you show the relevant template HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve this using lifecycle hooks of Angular. You can go through the [documentation of angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and use it as per your need.

Answer (score 1):

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

What you need is

> ngAfterViewInit()
>
> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views / the view that a directive is in.
>   Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked().